# Как получить имя пользователя windows средствами php?

Tags: php

Можно ли получить имя пользователя вошедшего под учетной записью средствами php?
Пробовал `$_SERVER` и `phpinfo`, не работает.

Comment: куда вошедшего?

Comment: @user331007 `$_SERVER['USERNAME']` __?__

Comment: @Эдуард не вариант , пусто

Comment: @teran на рабочий компьютер

Comment: Никак, php это серверный язык, без доступа к железу

Comment: @user331007 у меня в консоли `echo $_SERVER['USERNAME'];` вернул мой логин.

Comment: @user331007 вот ещё вариант: `echo explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, exec('whoami'))[1];` или так: `echo exec('whoami');`

Comment: @Эдуард может играет роль что компьютер находится  в доменной  группе,  и не работает

Comment: @user331007 у меня ПК тоже в доменной группе, именно поэтому я сперва написал пример для отделения домена от имени пользователя (_пример с explode()_) . Может имеет значение, где именно запускается срипт -- я не знаю. У меня php запускается в консоли.

Comment: @DaemonHK, php может использоваться не только для написания веб-приложений, но и для создания системных утилит. В данном случае тут не до конца ясен контекст.